# Drawing lines between all possible combinations of points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, network

I have a shapefile with several points (A, B, C, D, E,...) and I want to draw a line between all possible combinations of points (A-B, A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D,...).

As I know that it is quite simple in ArcGIS I don't want to use a Python-script or something similar. The "Points To Line" tool just draws me one line that is connecting all the points (A-B-C-D-...).

How can I do it using ArcGIS Desktop (all extensions available) ?

Comment: That will be a cool feature. I have not come across this before! Is this for any interesting analysis?

Comment: I think you can do this in two steps. First run "Generate Near Table", selecting Location. Next, run "XY to Line", providing start_x,start_y, near_x,near_y.  Generate Near Table requires an Advanced license.

Comment: Can you show a screen shot your attribute table?

Comment: Thank you klewis, I think this is a very simple and useful solution for the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer from klewis is very helpful:

> I think you can do this in two steps. First run "Generate Near Table", selecting Location. Next, run "XY to Line", providing start_x,start_y, near_x,near_y. Generate Near Table requires an Advanced license. – klewis

Answer (score 8):

WORKFLOW:

```py
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("points","points", "D:/Scratch/many.shp","JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY","INTERSECT", search_radius="1000000 Meters")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("many", "NEW_SELECTION", """"TARGET_FID" = "JOIN_FID"""")
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(in_features="many")
arcpy.AddField_management("many", "FromTo", "TEXT")
```

calculate field using:

```py
str(sorted([ !TARGET_FID!, !JOIN_FID!]))
```

Convert points to line:

```py
arcpy.PointsToLine_management("many", "D:/Scratch/lines.shp", Line_Field="FromTo")
```

RESULT:

[image: Results]

Comment: Nice solution. Worth emphasising that this all works as long as the search radius is big enough to encompass all points.

Comment: The search radius could easily be calculated by first calculating the extent of the dataset.