# ArcGIS Toolbox Python Script Validation: extracting field names from a multi-value list of feature classes

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I am writing a python script within an ArcGIS toolbox (not a Python Toolbox), that takes as input, a multivalue parameter of feature classes from which I would like to populate a second parameter with a drop down list of fields from the first feature class in the multivalue list. When using a single feature class as input, the field parameter can simply be set using the "Obtained from" functionality in the "Parameters" tab, but not so with a multivalue input. I am attempting to perform the operation using the validation classes instead. Below is my attempt using the "updateParameters" class. The validation doesn't fail, but doesn't produce a list of fields as expected. Any thoughts?

```
def updateParameters(self):
  """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
  validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
  has been changed."""

  if self.params[0].value:
      self.params[1].filter.list = arcpy.ListFields(self.params[0].valueAsText.split(";")[0])
  return
```

Edit - I’ve also tried:

```
[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(self.params[0].valueAsText.split(";")[0])]
```

With no success

Comment: List fields returns fields, you need their names.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I’ve tried that too, but it didn’t work either. Unless my syntax was wrong. I’ve edited my question code to reflect that.

Comment: Perhaps try to change type of 2nd parameter https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217192/draw-lines-between-all-possible-combinations-of-points-arcgis/217235#217235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation works:

```
  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value:
      lyr=self.params[0].valueAsText.split(";")[0]
      aList=[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(lyr)]
      self.params[1].value=aList
    return
```

if you launch tool from current mxd. Parameter of interest:

[image]

However, using hidden parameter (2) that is taking 1st entry from multiple layers list:

```
  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    self.params[2].enabled=0
    self.params[2].category = "Information Only"
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value:
      lyr=self.params[0].valueAsText.split(";")[0]
      self.params[2].value=lyr  
    return
```

Gives you more flexibility, because you'll be able to use filter on field types on parameter[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlqpI.png) while obtaining fields from hidden.