# Point to line tool to link all pairs of points in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, points-to-line

I have a series of points which I want to connect together as a web, with lines between all possible pairs of points. I'm sure I've done this before using the points to line geoprocessing tool, but I'm struggling to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been done before in ArcGIS Deskstop but requires some licenses. Please check this post for 2 solutions:
[Drawing lines between all possible combinations of points using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217192/drawing-lines-between-all-possible-combinations-of-points-using-arcgis-desktop)

See the following comment from @klewis:

> I think you can do this in two steps. First run "Generate Near Table",
> selecting Location. Next, run "XY to Line", providing start_x,start_y,
> near_x,near_y. Generate Near Table requires an Advanced license

Or the answer from @FelixIP for a ArcPy approach.
Not on a machine with ArcGIS Pro at the moment, so I can not double check for you.